# Minimizer of a class of SDEs

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, it.information-theory, stochastic-differential-equations, information-geometry

---

### Setup

- Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a separable Hilbert space, $\mathcal{X}\triangleq \langle \Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathscr{F}_t,\mathbb{P}\rangle$ be a stochastic base and $X_t$ be an $H$-valued stochastic process adapted to $\mathcal{X}$ satisfying the SDE:
  $$
  dX_t = \mu(t,X_t)dt + \Sigma(t,X_t)dW_t,
  $$
  where $W_t$ is a cylindrical Brownian-motion.
- Fix $\epsilon \geq 0$ and let $\mathscr{A}$ be the set of all pairs of bijective $\phi \in C^2(\mathscr{H},\mathscr{H}')$, and $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable functions $g:\mathscr{H}\mapsto \mathscr{H}$ satisfying
  $$
  \int_0^t P(g(X_s),\phi) ds \leq \epsilon,
  $$
  where $P$ is a fixed smooth functional depending on $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}\circ g(X_t)$.

*Note: In practice, for most $\phi$ the identity $g=1_{\mathscr{H}}$ rarely forms a pair $(\phi,g)$ in the $\mathscr{A}$.*

---

### Question

How can I solve the minimization problem:
$$
\operatorname{inf}_{(\phi,g)\in \mathscr{A}}\mathbb{E}[ D_{KL}(
     \phi\circ g(X_s),\phi(X_s))^2
],
$$
where $D_{KL}$ is the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Discrimination_information)

*(**however** if it simplifies the problem we may replace $D_{KL}(X,Y)$ with $(X-Y)$)*.